# Pandas left join in place

Tags: python, pandas, merge, left-join

I have a large data frame `df` and a small data frame `df_right` with 2 columns `a` and `b`. I want to do a simple left join / lookup on `a` without copying `df`.

I come up with this code but I am not sure how robust it is:

```
dtmp = pd.merge(df[['a']], df_right, on = 'a', how = "left")  #one col left join
df['b'] = dtmp['b'].values
```

I know it certainly fails when there are duplicated keys: [pandas left join - why more results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002355/pandas-left-join-why-more-results)

Is there better way to do this?

Related:

[Outer merging two data frames in place in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937462/outer-merging-two-data-frames-in-place-in-pandas)

[What are the exact downsides of copy=False in DataFrame.merge()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330490/what-are-the-exact-downsides-of-copy-false-in-dataframe-merge?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: For 1 column left join, convert to `pd.Series` and use `pandas.Series.map` :  `df['b']=df['a'].map(df_right.drop_duplicates('a').set_index('a')['b'])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there.
There are 4 cases to consider:

1. Both `df` and `df_right` **do not** have duplicated keys
2. Only `df` **has** duplicated keys
3. Only `df_right` **has** duplicated keys
4. Both `df` and `df_right` **have** duplicated keys

Your code fails in case 3 & 4 since the merging extends the number of row count in `df`. In order to make it work, you need to choose what information to drop in `df_right` prior to merging. The purpose of this is to enforce any merging scheme to be either case 1 or 2.

For example, if you wish to keep "first" values for each duplicated key in `df_right`, the following code works for all 4 cases above.

```
dtmp = pd.merge(df[['a']], df_right.drop_duplicates('a', keep='first'), on='a', how='left')
df['b'] = dtmp['b'].values
```

Alternatively, if column `'b'` of `df_right` consists of numeric values and you wish to have summary statistic:

```
dtmp = pd.merge(df[['a']], df_right.groupby('a').mean().reset_index(drop=False), on='a', how='left')
df['b'] = dtmp['b'].values
```

Comment: This is just what I needed, is there a way to only fill na's within a subset of columns from df_right to df?