# Pandas join inplace

Tags: python, pandas, join, in-place

Is there any way to do `df = df.join(df2)` but using the `inplace` argument available in many other functions? I.e. I want to do `df.join(df2, inplace=True)`. Of course this does not work because [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) does not have this argument, unlike many other functions in Pandas. How can I do this operation "`inplace`"?

Comment: There is no way to join this in place afaik. `df = df.join(df2)` is your best bet.

Comment: One alternative method here: [Pandas left join in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849102/pandas-left-join-in-place).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `join` does not have an `inplace` parameter. You will have to use `df = df.join(df2)`.

It is also worth mentioning that `inplace = True` isn't actually that great to use. It provides no real benefit to performance since most functions still create copies under the hood then at the final step overwrite the reference to the new transformed copy. It also can introduce bugs when mutating original datasets and can be hard to find later down the line.

This blog post explains this really well:
[Why You Should Probably Never Use pandas inplace=True](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-probably-never-use-pandas-inplace-true-9f9f211849e4)

In your case, even though you are reassigning the variable `df` to another dataframe, the original dataframe is kept intact.